# How to union some forms generated from models

Tags: python, django-models, django-forms

I try to create registration form. It consists of several forms UserForm, UserProfileForm and CompanyForm which are generated from models.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Company(models.Model):
    login = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    org = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    inn = models.BigIntegerField()
    kpp = models.BigIntegerField()


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.forms import HiddenInput
from django.forms.models import modelformset_factory

from models import Company, UserProfile


class CompanyRegistrationForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        exclude = ('login', 'password', 'is_active')


class UserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')


class UserProfileForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        exclude = ('user')
        widgets = {'company': HiddenInput()}
```

I try do this by formsets and inheritance but unfortunately.
I want one form with one custom save method, is it possible?

**ps** And my views.py is

```
class RegistrationCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'accounts/registration.html'
    model = Company
    #form_class = CompanyRegistrationForm
    success_url = 'thanks/'

    def _create_credentials(self):
        login_str = random.randint(1000000, 9999999)
        password = ''.join([symbol for i in range(10)
                            for symbol in random.choice(string.letters)])
        return login_str, password

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        form = context['registration_form']
        if form.is_valid():
            #TODO(mid): refactor this
            self.object = form.save()
            company_id = self.object.id
            login_str, password = self._create_credentials()
            self.object.password = password
            self.object.login = login_str
            self.object.is_active = True
            form.instance = self.object
            form.save()
            return self.success(login_str, password, company_id)
        return self.form_invalid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(RegistrationCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['registration_form'] = CompanyRegistrationForm()
        context['user_form'] = UserForm()
        context['user_profile_form'] = UserProfileForm()
        if self.request.POST:
            context['registration_form'] = CompanyRegistrationForm(self.request.POST)
            context['user_form'] = UserForm(self.request.POST)
            context['user_profile_form'] = UserProfileForm(self.request.POST)
        return context

    def success(self, login_str, password, company_id):
        login(self.request, self.object)
        self.request.session['company_id'] = company_id
        return render_to_response('accounts/thanks.html',
                                  {'login': login_str, 'password': password},
                                            RequestContext(self.request))
```

Comment: So you want to call one form that talks to many models, instead of many forms for many models?

Comment: Yes it is, if it's a possible.